# jQuery, use more than one event trigger?

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table that I am populating with information from a database table.  I have made the cells in the table editable upon click and have added jQuery to catch when the cell is done being edited (2.5 sec after last key press), ajax then sends info to a separate php file to update the database table with the changed value.  An issue that I have found is that if the cell is clicked out of to go into another cell and a change is made before those 2.5 seconds are up, the first change is never updated to the database.

**My Question Is:** If I would change to a field blur event instead, is there a way that I could still incorporate the timer so that ajax is reached when EITHER the field blur or the timeout are reached?

```
$('td').on('input', function() {
    var _this = $(this); // preserve reference to the input field here

    if(saveTimeout) clearTimeout(saveTimeout);
    saveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(_this)
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "updatedatabase.php",
            data: { 
                content: _this.text(), 
                date: _this.siblings().first().text(),
                prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + (_this.index() + 1) + ')').text(),
                old: old
            }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            alert( msg );
        });

    }, 2500);
});
```

Comment: Yes. You can use a timer on keyup and you can use a blur on the cell.  Instead, I would probably do a `keyup` event on the input in the field that first cancels the timeout then runs a timeout with a function in it. then add a blur event to the field to run the same function as made by the `keyup`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a different for `.setTimeout` delay depending on which event triggers it.

So on `blur`, it will not wait 2.5 sec to save, like on `input`.

**EDITED**
To prevent "double save", mark the `td` as saved.

```
var saveTimeout;

// Remove the "saved" class on keydown
$('td').on('keydown', function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("saved");
});

$('td').on('input blur', function(e) {
    console.log("event "+e.type+" occured");
    var timeoutDelay=2500;

    if( e.type == "blur" ){
        timeoutDelay=1;
    }

    // If NOT already saved...
    if( !$(this).hasClass("saved") ){
        var _this = $(this); // preserve reference to the input field here

        clearTimeout(saveTimeout);
        saveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(_this);

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "updatedatabase.php",
                data: { 
                    content: _this.text(), 
                    date: _this.siblings().first().text(),
                    prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + (_this.index() + 1) + ')').text(),
                    old: old
                }
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                alert( msg );
                // Add the "saved" class to prevent other saving
                _this.addClass("saved");
            });

            console.log("Ajax sent");

        }, timeoutDelay);
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution looks interesting, but if the last `td` is not clicked out of, the input blur event would never happen correct?  That is why I want the timer, so I catch people who never click out also

Comment: The timer on input still works... So if it is not clicked out OR if there was no input, it won't save.

Comment: Oh man im sorry, I didnt realize until looking again that input and blur are seperate events.  I feel pretty dumb now... LoL

Comment: lol... No problem. That's how we learn! This "dumb" feeling will engrave it deeper in your memory ;)

Comment: Haha yes they do.  I just tried this code and still have the same issue where if I change a second `td` after changing the first one without giving time in between, the first change does not take.

Comment: mmm... I think that's because `saveTimeout` was out of scope. I edited my answer and made other minor changes. I tested it in [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yVvLJx?editors=1011).

Comment: I dont understand... It seems to work on Firefox but not Chrome?

Comment: No reason for that. Try to empty your browser cache. ;)

Comment: I'm glad it helped ;)

Comment: hope you manage to find any other questions I may have, you were a huge help :-)

Comment: I just realized that this actually causes ajax to happen twice.  That causes data to be doubled.  How could I go about catching this so that after ajax happens once it kicks out instead of having the chance to ajax twice?

Comment: Wou'll have to "mark" the `td` as saved using a class. I will update my answer.

Comment: hmm... copied this and double checked line by line but I still get the alert message twice when allowing a timeout and still have my values doubled in the table

Comment: I made a new [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ENEQgv?editors=1111) to show you that is is *supposed to* work.